# How can I remove all selected DOM elements with Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am trying to remove the first column (and in general the n-th column) from a table with Mojolicious. 
I currently do it like this:

```
$table->find('td:first')->each(sub { my ($e) = @_; $e->remove });
```

but this isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

(Yeah I know I am asking a lot of questions on Mojolicious - just starting, and it's quite cool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [CSS Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for `:first`.

The following uses [`:nth-child(1)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) to isolate the first column and then [removes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#remove) the cells:

Could also have used [`:first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp), [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp), etc.  Be sure to check out all the different selectors available to be sure which ones will serve your purpose best.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

$dom->find('tr > td:nth-child(1)')->each( sub {$_->remove} );    

print $dom;

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1 Col 1</td><td>Row 1 Col 2</td><td>Row 1 Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2 Col 1</td><td>Row 2 Col 2</td><td>Row 2 Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3 Col 1</td><td>Row 3 Col 2</td><td>Row 3 Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 4 Col 1</td><td>Row 4 Col 2</td><td>Row 4 Col 3</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1 Col 2</td><td>Row 1 Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2 Col 2</td><td>Row 2 Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3 Col 2</td><td>Row 3 Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 4 Col 2</td><td>Row 4 Col 3</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS2 has a [`first-child` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child)

Comment: Aye, I mentioned and linked to that in my 3rd sentence.  The `first` he was using I suspect was drawn from the method call available in `Mojo::DOM` and therefore not actually a CSS Selector like he was using it.